# Iterating over a nested json with groovy

Tags: groovy

I have a json that i have defined in groovy

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def json = '''{
    "upperlevel1": {
      "lowerlevel1": "ABC",
      "lowerlevel2": "DEF"
    },
    "upperlevel2": {
      "lowerlevel1": "HIJ",
      "lowerlevel2": "KLM"
    }
}'''

def slurped = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)

slurped.each{ key, value ->
    key.each {k, v ->
        println "${v}"
    }
}
```

I expect to get the following output:

```
ABC
DEF
HIJ
KLM
```

Instead I get the following error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1$_run_closure1$_closure2.doCall() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [u]
```

Im running this inside the Jenkins groovy script tool.

What do I need to change here to correctly iterate over a nested JSON/hash? I see in the exception that it's getting stuck on the `u` from `upperlevel1` but I don't understand why.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I see now that my mistake was that I needed to iterate over the value (which is it's own map that contains key, values)

This is the fix

```
slurped.each{ key, value ->
    value.each {k, v ->
       println "${v}"
    }
}
```